# How to get a byte (UInt8) from an array of bytes ([UInt8])?

Tags: swift, byte, uint8t, uint8array

```
func readByte(bytes: [UInt8], offset: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    return bytes[offset] // Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt8]' with an index of type 'UInt8'
}
```

If you change the offset to any other Int will result in the same error. However if I use bytes[0] there is no problem. Probably because Swift knows what type to expect and converts the 0 accordingly. I am wondering what type that is.

Comment: `offset: Int` should work.

Comment: or `return bytes[Int(offset)]`

Comment: Martin R that was the only thing I haven't tried. UInt didn't work either. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are collections indexed by `Int`:

```
public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection {
    // ...
    public typealias Index = Int
    // ...
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Element
    // ...
}
```

In your case:

```
func readByte(bytes: [UInt8], offset: Int) -> UInt8 {
    return bytes[offset]
}
```